# Check if column not empty inside COUNTIFS function in zoho worksheet

Tags: worksheet-function, worksheet, zoho

I wanted to check if the value of A2 matches with the value of column Q, and in those matched rows, if column P has some value or not in my zoho worksheet. So I wrote this:

```
=COUNTIFS(sheet1.$Q:$Q; $A2; sheet1.$P:$P; "<>")
```

But here the not empty part "<>" doesn't work. What would be the syntax if I wanted to check the value of A2 with the Q column and also make sure there was some value in the P column?
I also made sure if I had something in the cells of P column, so I used

```
=COUNTA(sheet1.$P3:$P10000)
```

It gave me 1, where the previous COUNTIFS is giving me 74